# How to convert a "ppp" object to multitype object?

Tags: r, r-ppp

How can you convert a "ppp" object to **multitype object** in order to run a cross k `Kcross` function in r?

Comment: Mind providing some example data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign [factor](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html) levels as marks to obtain multitype point patterns in spatstat:

```
library(spatstat)
baa <- ppp(x = 1, y = 1, window = square(10))
is.multitype(baa)
[1] FALSE
marks(baa) <- "gaa"
is.multitype(baa)
[1] FALSE
marks(baa) <- factor("gaa")
is.multitype(baa)
[1] TRUE
```

Then you can run Kcross function:

```
moo <- ppp(x = c(1,2), y = c(2,1), window = square(5), marks = factor(c("baa", "gaa")))
Kcross(moo)
```